# I cannot get the favicon to work on my website?

Tags: html, favicon

I tried to implement a favicon to my website but it is not working properly.

I think the problem is that in my code, I am using  in the  twice, one for the href=style and one for the favicon but I don't know how to fix it.

this is my code at the moment:

```
<head>
<title>title</title>
<link href="faviconfinal.jpg" rel="icon">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `shortcut icon` instead of icon? Also, you also need to have a `favicon.ico` file in your root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `link type="shortcut icon"` I recommend you have a **png** file. What I normally do for `link` shortcut icons is that I prepare a 256x256 or 512x512 transparent png icon and just save it in a location like `images/icon.png`.

You should verify if the file is correctly located in your page. The easiest way to do this is opening your browser's console and looking for 404 errors. The easiest way to see it's working is the browser's tab showing your icon.

Besides that, what you must have is a `favicon.ico` file at your root folder (where your index file is located). The icon has to be a `.ico` file. For Windows you can use [IcoFX](https://icofx.ro/index.html). For mixed use or Mac focused you could use either [IconWorkshop](https://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/) or [IconFactory](https://iconfactoryapps.com/).

**You don't need to specify the favicon.ico icon, it's the default icon. You can check more on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Favicon)**

Comment: thanks this worked when i made the image an .ico file and put in the root folder with the index file

Answer (score 1):

Change the suffix of the `.jpg` file to `.ico`, rename it to `favicon.ico` and link to it as follows:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Comment: He can also have jpg or png's in a link tag. The only icon that forcefully has to be .ico is the root `favicon.ico` file and that one doesn't need any definitions.

Comment: I tried to save it as .ico but that filetype doesnt come up as a option to save it as and i tried to put .ico at the end of the filename but it didnt work

Comment: Does your OS maybe hide the file extensions? There's a setting to deactivate that to see all file extensions, and then you can change the suffix simply when you rename the file.